# asp.net mvc: read route param inside controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to read the a parameter that I've defined in a route from inside the controller.

The route:

```
routes.MapRoute(
"BusinessVoice", // Route name
"business/{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
new { controller = "Voice", action = "Index",
id = UrlParameter.Optional, locale = "business" } // Parameter defaults
);
```

From inside the controller I'd like to be able to read the route parameter **locale**, but have not idea where to look for it.

The controller:

```
namespace www.WebUI.Controllers
{
    public class VoiceController : Controller
    {
        public VoiceController()
        {
            ... want to read the locale param here
        }


        public ViewResult Index(string locale)
        {
            return View();
        }

    }
}
```

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dave,

This is from my basecontroller but you should be able to do exactly the same from a top level one too:

```
    protected override void Initialize(System.Web.Routing.RequestContext requestContext)
    {
        var locale = requestContext.RouteData.Values["locale"].ToString() ?? System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture.TwoLetterISOLanguageName;
        base.Initialize(requestContext);
    }
```

good luck

jim

Comment: you rock. thanks!
although I have no clue what System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture.TwoLetterISOLanguageName is :-)

Comment: Dave, that was purely my 'fallback' in the case of locale being null i.e. if the route is null... cheers

Answer (score 1):

```
    public VoiceController()
    {
        var locale = this.RouteData.Values["locale"];
    }
```

Comment: I would have thought that would work as well, but unfortunately not. 
I get:

    Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

If I move that same line of code down to the index action block, it works just fine.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't notice that you were in the constructor. You can't read *anything* from `this` in the constructor. As you say, it works fine in the action.